# How to open linux terminal from BIOS

Tags: linux, terminal, bios, shell, kali-linux

I edited the **/etc/profile** file by accident, and now I can't log in to my Linux Operating System.

I was thinking of doing this: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-path-directly , but I added those command lines (third step) at the end of the profile file...

How can I re-edit the profile file?, or better, how can I login again?

Comment: Use a live bootable drive, mount the root partition, edit the file, reboot.

Comment: Do u' know any video where I can to watch it? plz

Comment: Are you able to SSH as root to the machine? If yes, you could try something like 
`ssh root@<ip> echo "">/etc/profile` 
to at least reset it.

Comment: @fratester I guess not..

Comment: @fratester, I try it on Windows, but it say: The system cannot find the path specified.
Maybe I should do something else?

Comment: @Biswapriyo This video will can help me?: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLmHzBckjcE

Comment: Well, fully qualify the path: `/bin/echo `.
This should resolve the path issue.

Comment: Windows won't read your ext{2|3|4}fs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot open a linux terminal from the BIOS.  If you want to have a linux console or a terminal window, Linux must be running. In general, the boot process works as follows:

```
BIOS        does some Power On Self Tests, initialisations etc and then executes MBR
MBR         Master Boot Record executes Grub, Lilo or what you use
LILO        boots the kernel
KERNEL      initializes and starts Init; there are a number of variants, from 
            systemd to busybox.
INIT        Init then starts the different run-levels (depending on which init you use)
```

You must be in one of the init-phases to start a console or terminal.

There are a number of variations on this (uefi-boot, systemd's idea of runlevels, etc), but this is simplified how  your computer starts.

But, as a solution to your problem, @Biswapriyo's comment is correct: use a live-distro, mount your partitions and correct yuor `/etc/profile`; that is the easiest way.

Alternatively, you can try  to give the parameter `1` on the boot process. Press the spacebar within 3 seconds after the first booting and follow the booter's process. For `grub` it would be `a` to append a parameter (which should be `1`), but Lilo or others may differ.

Comment: Tnks, do u' know any video where I can to watch how to mount the root partition with a live bootable drive?

Comment: I have never understood the idea of video's for this kind of actions. Must be a generation issue. Anyway, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLmHzBckjcE should give some help.